# Identify JSON object from different table

Tags: php, mysql, json, xcode

I am trying to get data from three different tables (MySQL) using php script in xcode.

I know how to fetch elements from one table but I don't know how I can extend this method to be able to get the data from two other tables using the same php script and NSURLSession in xcode.

My php script for one table (working):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno(). ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$test = $mysqli->query($sql);
$Nrows = $test->num_rows;
$resultArray = array();

if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $resultArray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
else {
    echo 'oups.';
}
```

Now the problem is that I would like to do the same with two others tables. I tried to incorporate my fetching method in a separate php file (say getElementFunction.php) and calling this method in the main file:

**getElementFunction.php**

```
<?php
function getElements()
{
    $test = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $Nrows = $test->num_rows;
    $resultArray = array();

    if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $resultArray[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($resultArray);
    }
    else {
        echo 'oups.';
    }
}
?>
```

**main_file.php:**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno(). ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

include 'getElementFunction.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";
getElements() // --> how can I flag the json object as being returned from table 1

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table2";
getElements() // --> how can I flag the json object as being returned from table 2

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table3";
getElements() // --> how can I flag the json object as being returned from table 3
```

But I don't know if it is correct and how I could "flag" the different json objects that will be returned in order to be used in my xcode script. I would like to run the fetching process in one loop with only one URL.

Just in case, my objective-C script where I need a way to specify from which table is the json object returned...

**XCODE script with NSURLSession:**

```
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

        if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

            NSArray *deserializedArray = (NSArray *)jsonObject;

            if (deserializedArray.count > 0) {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    ...
                }
```

If someone could help me...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to clearly understand.. But you can try a foreach in getElements().

I mean :

```
function getElements(array $allSQL)
{
    //Final array to json_encode
    $finalResultsArray = array();

    foreach($allSQL as $tableName => $sqlStatement) {
            $arrayResults = array();

            $test = $mysqli->query($sqlStatement);
            $Nrows = $test->num_rows;

            if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlStatement)) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $arrayResults[] = $row;
                }
                //echo json_encode($arrayResults);
                $finalResultsArray[$tableName] = $arrayResults;
            }
            else {
                echo 'oups.';
            }

    }

    echo json_encode($finalResultsArray);
}
```

And this part :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";
getElements() // --> how can I flag the json object as being returned from table 1

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table2";
getElements() // --> how can I flag the json object as being returned from table 2

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table3";

getElements() // --> how can I flag the json object as being returned from table 3
```

Become this :

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM table1";

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table2";

$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM table3";

getElements(["table1"=> $sql1, "table2" => $sql2, "table3" => $sql3]);
```

Comment: It looks very nice thank you but I don't get any data back. I have a response (NSURLSession didReceiveResposne) but no data are coming back...

Comment: Unfortunatly, I am not familiar with XCode.. Try to dump `PHP` response of `getElements()` in order to idententify where issue is. _(Is this in my foreach or in conversion process from `JSON `object (rendered by `PHP` script) to `NSJSONSerialization` object ?)_

Comment: When I try var_dump($finalResultsArray); in the body of the function, it does not display anything (blank page...). :-(

Comment: it looks like the $mysqli defined in the main file is not recognized in the included file where I execute the loop. Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vars.php on line 14

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vars.php:14 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.php(23): getElements(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vars.php on line 14

Comment: okay, I had to add gobal $mysqli in the function body. Your code seems to work quite nicely, the error was in the was the array was defined. I had to define the array($table1=>$sql1,...) like this before calling getElements($array).

Comment: Nice ! Everything is working as you expected now ? If so, you can tick this answer :)

Comment: Yes, the error was in the getElements call. I had to remove the brackets [ ] to define an $array variable and then use it in the function call. I already ticked a few minutes ago. Should I do anything else?

Comment: Ok perfect ! Maybe this error was due to strongly typed `$allSQL` param used in `getElements()` function.. Heum, no, everything is down right ;p